# Why I am getting only the first row value from view to the controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = 1;

    $('.addScnt').on('click', function () {
        $('<tr class="p_scents">' +
              ' <td width="6%" colspan="1"><p>'+ (i + 1) +'</p></td>\n' +
              ' <td width="23%" colspan="4"><input type="text" name="ref_name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"></td>\n' +
              ' <td width="12.5%" colspan="1"><input type="text" name="ref_admission_year[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Year of Admission"></td>\n' +
              ' <td width="22.5%" colspan="3"><input type="text" name="ref_life_member_no[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Life Member No"></td>\n' +
              ' <td width="20%" colspan="3"><input type="text" name="ref_contact[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact no"></td>\n' +
              ' <td width="5%" colspan="3"><a  class="btn btn-danger remScnt" style="color:#fff;"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>\n' +
              '\n</tr>')
            .appendTo(scntDiv);

        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remScnt', function () {
        $(this).closest('.p_scents').remove();
        i = i - 1;
    });
});
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td width=2% colspan="1">
            <p>1</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="4">
            <input type="text" name="ref_name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        </td>
        <td colspan="1">
            <input type="text" name="ref_admission_year[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Year of Admission">
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="text" name="ref_life_member_no[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Life Member No">
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="text" name="ref_contact[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact no">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="table">
    <tbody id="p_scents" class="p_scents"></tbody>
</table>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="12" class="text-right addScnt">
            <h2>
                <a id="addScnt" class="btn btn-info" style="color: #FFF;">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add More
                </a>
            </h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is my controller:

```php
public function membership_registration_form_submit(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->ref_name as $i => $product) {
        $reference_info = new Reference_info();

        $reference_info->memberid = 13;
        $reference_info->ref_name = $request->ref_name[$i];
        $reference_info->ref_admission_year = $request->ref_admission_year[$i];
        $reference_info->ref_life_member_no = $request->ref_life_member_no[$i];
        $reference_info->ref_contact = $request->ref_contact[$i];

        $reference_info->save();
    }
}
```

I am getting only the first row data in the controller but I need all the row value generated from the view file.

I am generating the rows to get multiple row value using array but I can't get all the values in the array.

Please help, what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

The first tip I recommended is you generate a new [Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) file for clean code and a declare in it your fields so you validate your input:

##### `MembershipRegistartionRequest`

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MembershipRegistrationRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'ref_name' => ['required', 'array'],
            'ref_admission_year' => ['required', 'array'],
            'ref_life_member_no' => ['required', 'array'],
            'ref_contact' => ['required', 'array']
        ];
    }
}
```

Then I would write your code in the controller like this:

```php
public function store(MembershipRegistrationRequest $request)
{
    foreach ($request->ref_name as $i => $product) {
        $reference_info = new ReferenceInfo();

        $reference_info->member_id = 13;
        $reference_info->ref_name = $request->ref_name[$i];
        $reference_info->ref_admission_year = $request->ref_admission_year[$i];
        $reference_info->ref_life_member_no = $request->ref_life_member_no[$i];
        $reference_info->ref_contact = $request->ref_contact[$i];
        
        $reference_info->save();
    }

    dd(ReferenceInfo::get());
}
```

In the blade file which contains your forms, I would wrap the table in tag `<form></form>` like:

```html
<form action="{{ route('membership.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td width=2% colspan="1">
                <p>1</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <input type="text" name="ref_name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </td>
            <td colspan="1">
                <input type="text" name="ref_admission_year[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Year of Admission">
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">
                <input type="text" name="ref_life_member_no[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Life Member No">
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">
                <input type="text" name="ref_contact[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact no">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="table">
        <tbody id="p_scents" class="p_scents"></tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12" class="text-right addScnt">
                <h2>
                    <a id="addScnt" class="btn btn-info" style="color: #FFF;">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add More
                    </a>
                </h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

I just changed your code, `New` word should be `new`.

Below resulting `dd()`:

[image: Result dd]